# Building of BBv2 for libtorrent

Tags: python, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am following this [guide](http://www.libtorrent.org/building.html) to build libtorrent for `python 3.6`, but i'm stuck at this portion.

*Change directory to c:\boost_1_55_0\tools\jam\src. Then run the script called build.bat or build.sh on a unix system.*

`First you need to build bjam. You do this by opening a terminal (In windows, run cmd). Change directory to c:\boost_1_55_0\tools\jam\src. Then run the script called build.bat or build.sh on a unix system. This will build bjam and place it in a directory starting with bin. and then have the name of your platform. Copy the bjam.exe (or bjam on a unix system) to a place that's in you shell's PATH. On linux systems a place commonly used may be /usr/local/bin or on windows c:\windows (you can also add directories to the search paths by modifying the environment variable called PATH).`

I am using the latest build for `boost` [here](http://www.boost.org/) which is 1.65.1. All i've done is to extract it to a folder.

**Issue**

I don't see a `build.bat` within this specific folder that i should be using to build `bjam` with. Is there a more clearer way to install libtorrent on windows for python?

Answer (score 0):

you could get a boost installer separately, with a prebuilt bjam and boost-build. e.g. [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.65.1/) or [this](https://boost.teeks99.com/) .

The issue with those instructions is that newer versions of the boost package moved things around a bit. You'll now find the bjam build script at:

/tools/build/src/engine

Comment: Thanks for this! I haven't had the time to give this a try yet. But will check it out over the weekend! :)

Comment: Just wondering, if I were to use the prebuild bjam and boost-build that you have linked, I can skip directly to step 3 of your tutorial?

Comment: that's right. although, it's possible you have to configure which compilers you have still, in user-config.jam